# Getting type errors using vue.js single web page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting some really strange type errors that are really vague and are inhibiting my web page from rendering, Could anyone that's better using vue.js/html/CSS help me out? Thanks

I have received the following errors in the console in chrome dev tools...

- Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
- vue.js:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property 'dt_txt' of undefined

  Weather App

  ```
  <body>

      <div id='app'>
          <h1>Today's Weather</h1>
          <h2 class="flex-container">
              <span>Today: {{forecast[0].dt_txt}} </span>
              <span>Temperature: {{forecast[0].main.temp}} F</span>
              <span>Sky Conditions: {{forecast[0].weather[0].description}}</span>
              <span>Humidity: {{forecast[0].main.humidity}}</span>
              <span>Pressure: {{forecast[0].main.pressure}}</span>
          </h2>

          <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1>
          <h2 class="flex-container">
              <fpan class="forecast-container-default" v-for="index in 39" :key="index" v-bind:id="giveID(index)" v-on:click="changeColor($event, index)">
                      <tpan>Day: {{forecast[index].dt_txt}} </tpan>
                      <tpan>Temperature: {{forecast[index].main.temp}} F</tpan>
                      <tpan>Sky Conditions: {{forecast[index].weather[0].description}}</tpan>
                      <tpan>Humidity: {{forecast[index].main.humidity}}</tpan>
                      <tpan>Pressure: {{forecast[index].main.pressure}}</tpan>
              </fpan>
          </h2>
      </div>



      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
      <script src="style.css"></script>
      <script>


          const app = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
              zip: "",
              id: "",
              ip: "",
              forecast: "",
              isActive: false              
          },
          methods: {
              changeColor : function(event, id) {
                  console.log(id);
                  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "lightyellow";
                  return document;
              },
              giveID : function(index) {
                 return String(index);                                    
              },

          },
          created () {
              url = "http://api.ipstack.com/"

              fetch("http://api.ipstack.com/24.11.12.118?access_key=74dd3f021bba199c25e59418416fc4bd")
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => {
              this.zip = json.zip
              this.ip = json.ip
              })
          },

          created () {
              url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?APPID=cd3f3e553d9d58b1125ce354b20bca30&units=imperial&zip=84321"
              console.log(this.zip)
              fetch(url)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => {
                  console.log(this.zip)
                  this.forecast = json['list']

              })
          },     

      })
  </script>
  </body>
  ```

CSS File

```
html {
    background-color: beige;
}

head {
    vertical-align: 5px;
}

h1 {
    font-style: oblique;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    border: 5px;
    border-color: black;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    display: inline-flex;
}

h2 span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

h2 tpan {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

h2 fpan {

    width: fit-content;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 5px;
}
#id{
    font-weight: bolder;
}

tr > td {
    font-size: 20px;
}



.forecast-container-default{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 3;
    font-size: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;  
}

.forecast-container-likely{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 3;
    font-size: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.forecast-container-unlikely{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 3;
    font-size: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
}


.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: aqua;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Also here is the api model that I am using.

{"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji",
"coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},
"country":"JP",
"cod":"200",
"message":0.0045,
"cnt":38,
"list":[{
        "dt":1406106000,
        "main":{
            "temp":298.77,
            "temp_min":298.77,
            "temp_max":298.774,
            "pressure":1005.93,
            "sea_level":1018.18,
            "grnd_level":1005.93,
            "humidity":87,
            "temp_kf":0.26},
        "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
        "clouds":{"all":88},
        "wind":{"speed":5.71,"deg":229.501},
        "sys":{"pod":"d"},
        "dt_txt":"2014-07-23 09:00:00"}
        ]}

Comment: Please create a **minimal** complete verifiable example that showcases the problem along with the **entire** stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the errors.

- Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

Based on your template, this error is being thrown here

`<span>Temperature: {{forecast[0].main.temp}} F</span>`

What's `forecast`? It looks like it's supposed to be an array. Looking at your `data`, `forecast` is initialized as an empty string. Accessing `[0]` of an empty string is undefined, so therefore, you cannot read property 'main' of undefined. Either adjust your data or template to accommodate empty data.

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Idk what this is, but it should tell you the line number.

- vue.js:1743 TypeError: Cannot read property 'dt_txt' of undefined

Same reason as the first bullet point.

I usually handle empty data by toggling between a loading/loaded state. Here's a
 minimal example.

```
<body>

    <div id='app'>
        <h1>Today's Weather</h1>
        <div v-if="isLoading">
            // show loading icon, spinner, text, whatever 
         </div>
        <div v-else>
            // render the data 
            <h2 class="flex-container">
                <span>Today: {{forecast[0].dt_txt}} </span>
                <span>Temperature: {{forecast[0].main.temp}} F</span>
                <span>Sky Conditions: {{forecast[0].weather[0].description}}</span>
                <span>Humidity: {{forecast[0].main.humidity}}</span>
                <span>Pressure: {{forecast[0].main.pressure}}</span>
            </h2>

            <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1>
            <h2 class="flex-container">
                <fpan class="forecast-container-default" v-for="index in 39" :key="index" v-bind:id="giveID(index)" v-on:click="changeColor($event, index)">
                        <tpan>Day: {{forecast[index].dt_txt}} </tpan>
                        <tpan>Temperature: {{forecast[index].main.temp}} F</tpan>
                        <tpan>Sky Conditions: {{forecast[index].weather[0].description}}</tpan>
                        <tpan>Humidity: {{forecast[index].main.humidity}}</tpan>
                        <tpan>Pressure: {{forecast[index].main.pressure}}</tpan>
                </fpan>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="style.css"></script>
    <script>


        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
              isLoading: false,             
        },
        created () {
            this.isLoading = true

            url = "http://api.ipstack.com/"

            fetch("http://api.ipstack.com/24.11.12.118?access_key=74dd3f021bba199c25e59418416fc4bd")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
              this.zip = json.zip
              this.ip = json.ip
              this.isLoading = false
            })
            // make sure to catch any errors and turn off isLoading
            // or else you'll be loading forever. async/await makes
            // this easier since you can use try-catch-finally
        },


    })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: i think the `this.isLoading = false` should sit in the callback.(in the `then` block of `fetch()`) otherwise we're still not sure that we got the data when we render the fields, dont you think?